# Mixed content issue on Symfony + Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius, payum

So I'm writing a project using Symfony + Sylius. I have a form which gets submitted via ajax to a `/{paymentId}/pay` route, this in turn calls the payum controller which handles the payment and sends a redirect to `/payment/capture/{token}` which then redirects again to display a card details form, this card details form is loaded in an iFrame. However, the route for `/payment/capture` is served via http and therefore never appears in the iFrame due to this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/checkout/complete' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://www.example.com/payment/capture/SOMETOKENVALUE'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

How can I force the payment/capture route to server https? I've tried a few things such as adding

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

to my templates and setting the scheme requirement in my order.yml:

```
sylius_shop_order_pay:
    path: /{paymentId}/pay
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.payum:prepareCaptureAction
        requirements:
            _scheme:  https
        _sylius:
            redirect:
                route: sylius_shop_order_after_pay

sylius_shop_order_after_pay:
    path: /after-pay
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.payum:afterCaptureAction
        requirements:
            _scheme:  https
```

However since the actual /payment/capture route is generated at run time, I'm not sure if I can force it onto https.

I have also tried via access control:

```
access_control:

    - { path: ^/payment, role: ROLE_NO_ACCESS, requires_channel: https}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

complete.html.twig:

```
    {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('sylius_shop_checkout_complete'), 'attr': {'class': 'ui loadable form final-step', 'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'target' : 'card-details'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    {% include 'SyliusShopBundle:Common/Order:_summary.html.twig' with {'edit': true} %}

    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}

    <iframe width="100%" height="670px" name="card-details" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

checkout.js:

```
let form = jQuery("form[name='sylius_checkout_complete']");

if (form.length) {
    form.submit()
}
```

Comment: `to display a card details form, this card details form is loaded in an iFrame` post the relevant code/template please

Comment: question updated

Comment: What is the url generated for `sylius_shop_checkout_complete`?

Comment: /checkout/complete, same page as where form is loaded.

Comment: I'm confused then, what generates the folowing url: `http://www.example.com/payment/capture/SOMETOKENVALUE`?

Comment: found the route that does and overrode it to force https:

`payum_capture_do:
    path: /payment/capture/{payum_token}
    defaults: { _controller: sylius.controller.payum.capture:doAction }
    schemes:  [https]
`

The only problem is now I get too many redirects -.-